# java.io.IOException: Batch scripts can only be run on Windows nodes ::: With jenkins - MacOSX

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ioexception

I'm new with Jenkins and i want to execute commands using a node, but I have the following error:
***java.io.IOException: Batch scripts can only be run on Windows nodes.***

My node is:

```
node ('master') {
  git 'https://github.com/bryaneibon/SeleniumWithCucucumber.git'
  bat label: '', script: 'mvn verify'
}
```

When I delete the bash command, everything works perfectly.

By trying with the command:

```
node ('master') {
  git 'https://github.com/bryaneibon/SeleniumWithCucucumber.git'
  bat 'mvn verify'
}
```

I have exactly the same error.

***The condensed log is as follows:***

```
No credentials specified
> /usr/local/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> /usr/local/bin/git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/bryaneibon/SeleniumWithCucucumber.git 
# timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/bryaneibon/SeleniumWithCucucumber.git
> /usr/local/bin/git --version # timeout=10
> /usr/local/bin/git fetch --tags --force --progress -- 
.
. 
.
[Pipeline] bat
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: Batch scripts can only be run on Windows nodes
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.WindowsBatchScript.doLaunch(WindowsBatchScript.java:58)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launchWithCookie(FileMonitoringTask.java:106)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:99)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:317)
.
.
.
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Why are you using the `bat` command if you aren't on Windows? Based on https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/, it looks like you might want `sh` instead, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Exactly! Since you are on Linux, replace `bat` with `sh`.

Comment: @SomethingDark That should be an answer

Comment: @KrishnaKumarSingh - I don't post answers when I'm just guessing